# MenuItem IsChecked Property NOT Binding to VM Property

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, menuitem, ischecked

Hello I am a new WPF/MVVM programmer and having trouble with a MenuItem.

I have a menu who's ItemsSourced are binded to an object I created;

```
        <Menu Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="menuProfile" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="58" >
        <MenuItem Header="Profiles" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProfileList}" DisplayMemberPath="ProfileName" >
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/> 
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

When I run this I can see all my items in the menu but my property **IsSelected** isn't getting updated.

```
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set 
        { 
            _isSelected = value;
            GetProfileConfigInfo();        
        }
    }
```

If I take the style container out and put the **IsCheckable** and **IsChecked** values in line with the MenuItem....

```
<MenuItem Header="Profiles" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProfileList}" DisplayMemberPath="ProfileName" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
```

my property **IsSelected** gets updated but I can't see any of the items in my menu just the header *Profiles*.

And idea on what I'm doing wrong????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setter for IsSelected, you need to call OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected").

I think this could fix your problem.

I copied your exact code (below) into Blend, and created a sample data source with your exact property names, and the checkboxes in the menu worked properly.

```
<Menu Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="menuProfile" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="58" >
    <MenuItem Header="Profiles" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProfileList}" DisplayMemberPath="ProfileName" >
        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/> 
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```